# Is it possible to create translateable arbitrary XML resources in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-xml

I want to create an app which asks the user questions, scores the answers and potentially react to them presenting subsequent questions. For this I thought of something like the following XML in `res/xml/questions.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<questions>
    <question id="000" category="2">
        <text>Yes or no?</text>
        <answers>
            <choice id="0" score="+5">Yes</choice>
            <choice id="1" score="-5">No</choice>
        </answers>
    </question>
    <question id="010" category="1">
        <parent id="000" choice="0"/>
        <text>Whats my question?</text>
        <answers>
            <choice id="0" score="-5">Shut up.</choice>
            <choice id="1" score="0">I don't care.</choice>
            <choice id="2" score="+5">I like your attitude!</choice>
        </answers>
    </question>
</questions>
```

I want to support multiple languages. How can I translate the contents of `<text>` and `<choice>` without redefining the same logic in different XMLs? (Or should I abandon the XML approach altogether?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some options:

Option #1: Have `res/xml/questions.xml` and other variants of that XML for different languages (e.g., `res/xml-es/questions.xml`, `res/xml-de/questions.xml`, `res/xml-zh/questions.xml`)

Option #2: Where you have the English strings, instead have values that map to string resources. So, `res/xml/questions.xml` might look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<questions>
    <question id="000" category="2">
        <text>question_000</text>
        <answers>
            <choice id="0" score="+5">question_000_choice_0</choice>
            <choice id="1" score="-5">question_000_choice_1</choice>
        </answers>
    </question>
    <question id="010" category="1">
        <parent id="000" choice="0"/>
        <text>question_010</text>
        <answers>
            <choice id="0" score="-5">question_010_choice_0</choice>
            <choice id="1" score="0">question_010_choice_1</choice>
            <choice id="2" score="+5">question_010_choice_2</choice>
        </answers>
    </question>
</questions>
```

Then you would have string resources for `question_000`, `question_000_choice_0`, and so on. When you parse the XML, you then use `getIdentifier()` on a `Resources` object to look up the string resource ID corresponding with something like `question_000_choice_0`.

Option #3: Have the XML simply describe the basics:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<questions>
    <question id="000" category="2">
        <answers>
            <choice id="0" score="+5" />
            <choice id="1" score="-5" />
        </answers>
    </question>
    <question id="010" category="1">
        <parent id="000" choice="0"/>
        <answers>
            <choice id="0" score="-5" />
            <choice id="1" score="0" />
            <choice id="2" score="+5" />
        </answers>
    </question>
</questions>
```

You would still have string resources for `question_000`, `question_000_choice_0`, and so on. However, instead of having those names in the XML, you would just generate them from the question and choice IDs.

Comment: Thank you very much! I decided to go for option three and added a minimal *t*-attribute to both question and choice, so i know what those entities are all about.