# Is it possible to use an arbitrary name for an XML resource file in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

I'm attempting to create a 'Preferences' Activity for my Wear OS app (home-baked as I don't believe the standard Settings Activity copes with round screens).

In order to support the round screen I am planning to use a `WearableRecyclerView` and so need to define `string-array`s for the contents of the Recycler layouts.

To keep things clean in my code, I'd like to keep these string-arrays out of my strings.xml files if possible.

Therefore, is it possible to use, for example, `preferences.xml` in the `res/values` folder (and provide translations in the `values-??` folders) and then reference this in code?

I have tried creating `preferences.xml` but when I try to retrieve the arrays with

```
String[] prefsTitlesArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.preferences.prefs_titles);
```

I get an error flagged in the IDE as 'preferences' isn't recognised under R.

Do I have to stick to the standard `.xml` file names such as `strings.xml` and `array.xml` or is it possible to use an arbitrary file name under the values tree to keep thinsg nice and clean and obviously named?

(Note, I have looked at [Is it possible to create translateable arbitrary XML resources in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56175772/is-it-possible-to-create-translateable-arbitrary-xml-resources-in-android-studio) which seems to imply that arbitrary xml file names might be possible outside of the values tree, but doesn't mention how they are referenced in code (Java, in my case).

Comment: The file names don't matter; you can name them whatever you like. All of the files in `res/values/` are processed for whatever's inside their `<resources>` elements. You can certainly have a `preferences.xml` file there, but its `<string>`s, `<array>`s, etc. will still be compiled into the same `R` classes as they always are. That is, your array's identifier is `R.array.prefs_titles`, no matter which file it's in.

Comment: Thanks MIke, I didn't realise that. If you put that in an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Oh, I'm good. :-) Nothin' huge. Thanks, though. I appreciate the offer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Mike M's comment, yes it is possible to name the XML resource files anything you want as the code reference `R.????.itemName` is derived from the item **type** not the file it comes from.

So a file called `prefs.xml` could contain `<string name="itemName">` items and `<string-array name="itemName">` items etc and they will be referenced from code as `R.string.itemName` and `R.array.itemName`.

The XML filename itself is irrelevant so long as it is saved in the correct folder within the project for value resource files.